# Encountering issues with button switches in PyCharm GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to implement a GUI with PyCharm and would like to be able to use multiple switches as seen in the code below. Unfortunately, the switches only seem to work 1 at a time while the other 1 doesn't do anything when clicked on. Is there any way we can make both of them work while being in the same code?
Also, as it appears the black background is only active after the switch image has been clicked at least once. Is there any way to make the black background active by default?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import serial
import time
import os

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='black')

rootWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
rootHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

switch_variable = tkinter.StringVar(value="off")
global is_on
is_on = True

switch_variable2 = tkinter.StringVar(value="reverse2")
global is_forward
is_forward = True

# This part of the code allows constant font size for all monitor screens
normalWidth = 1920
# Width of monitor screen used to write this code
normalHeight = 1080
# Height of monitor screen used to write this code

percentWidth = rootWidth / (normalWidth / 100)
percentHeight = rootHeight / (normalHeight / 100)
scale = ((percentWidth + percentHeight) / 2) / 100
fontstyle = tkFont.Font(family='Cambria', size=50)

def switch():
    global is_on
    if is_on:
        on_button.config(image=on, bg='black', bd=0, activebackground='black', command=switch)
        is_on = False
    else:
        on_button.config(image=off, bg='black', bd=0, activebackground='black', command=switch)
        is_on = True

def switch2():
    global is_forward
    if is_forward:
        forward_button.config(image=forward2, bg='black', bd=0, activebackground='black', command=switch2)
        is_forward = False
    else:
        reverse_button.config(image=reverse2, bg='black', bd=0, activebackground='black', command=switch2)
        is_forward = True

forward2 = Image.open("C:/Users/LattePanda/Desktop/images/LedOn.png")
reverse2 = Image.open("C:/Users/LattePanda/Desktop/images/LedOff.png")

on = Image.open("C:/Users/LattePanda/Desktop/images/forward.png")
off = Image.open("C:/Users/LattePanda/Desktop/images/reverse.png")

resizeOn = on.resize((600,600),Image.ANTIALIAS)
resizeOff = off.resize((600,600),Image.ANTIALIAS)

resizeOn2 = forward2.resize((400,400),Image.ANTIALIAS)
resizeOff2 = reverse2.resize((400,400),Image.ANTIALIAS)

on = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizeOn)
off = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizeOff)

forward2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizeOn2)
reverse2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizeOff2)

on_button = Button(root,image=on, bd=0,activebackground='black',command=switch)
on_button.pack(pady=50)
off_button = Button(root,image=off, bd=0,activebackground='black',command=switch)

forward_button = Button(root,image=forward2, bd=0,activebackground='black',command=switch2)
forward_button.pack(pady=50)
reverse_button = Button(root,image=reverse2,bd=0,activebackground='black',command=switch2)

master=tkinter.Tk()
master.title("place() method")
master.geometry("450x350")

master.mainloop()
root.after(0, update, 0)
root.mainloop()

on_button.pack(pady=50)
label_on = Label(root, text="LED: ON",image=on,activebackground='black',height=400,width=400)
label_on.pack(padx=100,pady=50)

label_off = Label(root, text="LED: OFF",image=off,activebackground='black',height=400,width=400)
label_off.pack(padx=50,pady=50)

forward_button.pack(pady=50)
label_forward = Label(root, text="Forward",image=forward,activebackground='black',height=500,width=500)
label_forward.pack(padx=100,pady=50)

label_reverse = Label(root, text="Reverse",image=reverse,activebackground='black',height=500,width=500)
label_reverse.pack(padx=50,pady=50)

#switch_frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is long. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).     Also, there are a few mistakes in your code. Avoid importing everything from a module. Avoid importing a module multiple times. No need to use ```global``` outside a function. It is already global variable.

Comment: Try using `background` rather that `activebackground` to make the background black by default. Do this where you create the buttons. Also you have more than one instance of `Tk` and calls to `mainloop` in your code. This will cause problems. If you want a new window, use `Toplevel` rather than `Tk`

Comment: @scotty3785 Thank you for the recommendations. However, if I want to use another button instead of a window, what would you recommend?